# Unable to save the invoice magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I recently reindex all my magento e-commerce site. After when i try to save an invoice it gave me " Unable to save the invoice"

When i looked at the log file, i see this error :

1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`website_database/eav_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTITY_TYPE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DEL)

Do you have any idea how can i fix this ?

Comment: Are your db name `website_database`?

Comment: No i just omitted the name from privacy reasons